# How to put content in a multi dimensional array in jquery.javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a function which is triggered on by the click of an update button. When the button is clicked all the elements in a list from a particular div are captured. Each list has about 3 to 4 data attributes. I want create an array in jquery or javascript where the created array is grouped by certain data attributes. Below is the function am using

```
    <div>
        <ul id="listDiv" >
            <li  style="" id="id1" data-type="edit"  data-seq="1"  data-name="name1">Name1</li>
            <li  style="" id="id2" data-type="edit"  data-seq="2"  data-name="name2">Name2</li>
            <li  style="" id="id3" data-type="create"  data-seq="3"  data-name="name3">Name3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<a class='upBtn' > Update </a>

$('.upBtn').on('click', function(){
    var data = [];
    $('#lisDiv li').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
    data[type]= [];
    data[type][id] = [];
    data[type][id]['type'] = $(this).attr('data-type');   
    data[type][id]['seq'] = $(this).attr('data-sequence');   
    data[type][id]['name'] = $(this).attr('data-name');  

    });
    console.log(data);
})
```

I tried using push as much as possible. But I am not getting the result I  intended. I want the result to be like the format, below:

```
[edit] => [id1] => ('type') => 'edit',
                   ('seq') => 2,
                    ('name') => 'name1'
          [id2] => ('type') => 'edit',
                   ('seq') => 1,
                    ('name') => 'name2'
[create] => [id3] => ('type') => 'edit',
                   ('seq') => 3,
                    ('name') => 'name3'
          [id4] => ('type') => 'edit',
                   ('seq') => 4,
                    ('name') => 'name4
```

'

But whenever I try the array is not getting pushed. I am not sure how to use push here. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to set properties on an array instead of an object. Try `data[type][id] = {};` instead. But it's probably possible to create the arrays directly by mapping a better selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take objects instead of arrays.

By taking array, you get still the properties, but you can neither see them with `console.log`, nor stringify them, because an array is stringified with the numerical (positive 32 bit integer) indices.

```
var data = {};
// ...
data[type] = data[type] || {};
data[type][id] = {};
```

In your code, you have the wrong identifier, it should be `listDev` and you need to use a default value for assigning the `type`.

```js
$('.upBtn').on('click', function() {
    var data = {};
    $('#listDiv li').each(function() {        // listDiv spelling
        var id = $(this).attr('id'),
            type = $(this).attr('data-type');

        data[type] = data[type] || {};        // prevent overwriting the object
        data[type][id] = {
            type: $(this).attr('data-type'),
            seq: $(this).attr('data-seq'),    // seq instead of sequence
            name: $(this).attr('data-name')
        };
    });
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="listDiv">
    <li style="" id="id1" data-type="edit" data-seq="1" data-name="name1">Name1</li>
    <li style="" id="id2" data-type="edit" data-seq="2" data-name="name2">Name2</li>
    <li style="" id="id3" data-type="create" data-seq="3" data-name="name3">Name3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a class='upBtn'>Update</a>
```

Comment: i tried this but getting only 1 id  data. Probably the last 1. should i be using push. If yes where exactly should i use

Comment: please add some html with the data.

Comment: I've added html with little data.

Comment: Okay thank you. This ` data[type] = data[type] || {};  ` this line was actually cauing the error. Can you pls tell what this does.

Comment: it takes a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) `data[type]`, which is an object, or an array or every not empty string, or a number which is not zero or `NaN`, **or** the following item, in this case the object. the reason for this pattern, you could simply check and assign in a s ingle step.

Comment: ok thank you very much. Just asking is this not possible using array []

Comment: as default value (yes) or at all in this code (no)?